# Memory Leak issue in objective c

Tags: ios, xcode, memory, memory-leaks, nsdictionary

I have been fighting a memory leak, well a little more then one it just happens to mostly be in the same location. I have this issue where I am using a class to store global information that is needed through out the code because it stores the list of food that a user adds to their meal plan. The issue that I have is that one it is a relatively large data structure that I am using. The data structure is a dictionary with keys to five other dictionaries that all have 8 mutable arrays that can be as large as the user wishes due to the fact that can add as much food as their heart desires.

I have set the structure like so

```
mealInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]
[mealInfo setObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionary] forKey:"foo"];
[[mealInfo objectForKey:"such"] setObject: [NSMutableArray array] forKey:"bar"];
```

this is repeated for the complete data structure. This did seem to solve some of my possible memory leaks when I analyzed in xcode. The issue is further then that cause I have an idea what the issue is just not the solution. I have objects created, which create this structure in the local scope of the .m file I am in. I go save this structure in the class where mealInfo is created, not the local scope, with a static object of that class. (*I am not using too much code because it is one in a lot of locations and two is way too many lines*)

After I save to the static variable of the class I release the local scope, I can not release the mealInfo because when I have done that in the past it actually causes the object to disappear and nil in the class that it was initialized in making it inaccessible to other classes trying to access this information.

One solution I thought of was to have all the saving and storing occur in the class in which it was initialized and just use getters and setters, but was trying to make it more readily accesible by making it an object that can be called from other classes and changed in those classes which becomes a little more complicated and confusing at times. This I was trying to avoid. I will do that if that is the only solution, but would like to get this method to work first.

I hope this is not too confusing. I also hope someone might have a solution to this memory leak. Thank you all for the time at least to read all of this.

Comment: It sounds like a job for core data.

Comment: Do you have an example of this cause I am not sure what that object is really like. I saw the wiki on it. Is it completely different from an NSObject? I guess I am not sure how that would be set up. I do see that the wiki explains pretty much what I want since I want to manipulate and read without worrying about the memory part of things, which we all know is such a fun thing to have wrong with the code :-)

Comment: If you haven't read it already, read the [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) and check out the related samples.

Comment: I will get right on that. Thank you.

Comment: sure. i know it doesn't answer your question directly, but i think it's the better solution for your ultimate goal. if you find that works for you, drop a comment saying so. cheers.

Comment: You are right and I am actually using Core Data just didn't know it as that because of to me it was just classes and methods, but I will tell you that you should put yours as an answer. The solution to my problem is specific to my data structure and feel your comment is more general which is a good thing for users to look at. My solution was that I needed to go back to static variables in the class instead of creating multiple class, thus creating multiple instances and not releasing them correctly. With the static variables in the class and having the class do all the work it cured the leaks.

Comment: I'm glad to hear you found your solution. I don't think my comments warrant an answer, but I do think you should put the solution you used as an answer to your question. As part of that answer, I suggest you abstract a simple example out of your issue and demonstrate your solution. You might want to be careful how you implement static CoreData objects. I haven't seen enough of your code, but my instinct tells me, you may not need take that approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little hard to understand your question... but if `mealInfo` itself is your static class variable then you can alloc it once - and once only - by doing the following.

```
if (!mealInfo)
    mealInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

Otherwise you have to release it each time you alloc it, or it will leak.

Comment: I actually found a solution awhile ago and I think it was this but forgot to answer the question myself so thank you.